# How can I logout from all the unused sandboxes I have in my machine?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli

Or rather how to remove the orgs I don't use anymore. Is there an easy way to "remove all orgs unused for 90+ days"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no such command to automatically logout from multiple orgs at once, being a command line you can easily automate this with your OS's favorite scripting language, such as Powershell on Windows or Bash in Unix systems.

The following example logs out from all non-scratch orgs that have "Auth" in the "connected status" attribute (which generally means an auth error after someone changes the user's password or refreshes the org, which is the case with most consultancy services).

> Note: this runs in an Unix system with `jq` installed.

```bash
jq '.result.nonScratchOrgs[]' < $(sfdx org list --json) | jq -c 'select(.connectedStatus | contains("Auth"))' | while read i; do
  echo ">>>"; sfdx auth logout -u $(jq -s '.username' <<< $i) -p
done
```

You could create a filter for the [date parameter using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881728/jq-filter-json-by-dates) too, if needed.